# How to ignore Eclipse task tags in certain directories?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, helios

In Eclipse (HELIOS) there is an option to scan all source code and search for task tags such as "TODO", "FIXME" etc. 
 The result is then shown in a fine list. 
One can access this list by: Windows->Show View->Tasks.
However, it also scans resources directory and libraries, whose task tags are not of my interest. 
How can I filter Task Tags searching by directory exclusion filter?
10x

Comment: Please check if the most voted answer solve your problem and mark it as accepted instead of current accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is that this is not currently possible. You can configure the set of task keywords on a per-project basis along with the priority of each, but no more than that.

Comment: That's not true (any more?). See Dmitrys answer.

Comment: Confirming that Dmitry's answer works great (Eclipse Neon), and having this as the accepted answer as no longer accurate.

Answer (score 31):

It is possible.

1. Open the Tasks view. Then press icon with the down arrow (top right corner of the window, next to minimise button) and press "Configure Contents..."
2. Either add new configuration or modify TODOs
3. In the Scope section select "On working set:" and press button "Select..." to create a new workspace
4. Create a new workspace with only selected folders that you want to include

Comment: After performing the above mentioned steps it may still be showing all the tasks. You need to press the down arrow button again > Show > "TODOs" or the newly created configuration you made in step 2.

Comment: I also needed to restart Eclipse.

Comment: In current Eclipse (here: 9-2023) you have to open "Filters ..." instead of "Configure Contents ..." which is not there anymore. Don't get confused by "Configure Columns ..."!

Answer (score 4):

Also there is the way I work around that limitation: Define your own tags, i.e. by adding your name or some shortcut and use the task-list's filter function to ignore the rest.

In the preferences you can define your own TODO Tags (for highlighting purposes etc.) or you can leave it with TODO, FIXME, XXX..

Also in the preferences you can redefine the default Comments like "TODO: Auto-generated something" to "TODO Nir: Auto..."

In the Task List you can then filter for exactly those tags.

Cheers,
 Rob